# Arrow symbol in for loop

Tags: java

On a few occasions I have seen an arrow like symbol combination being used in a for loop like such:

```
for(int i = 100; i --> 0;) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

What's happening here?

Comment: That's the "goes to" operator. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/1288

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 100).forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.println(99 - i));`

Comment: Your version is a very odd way to write `for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: I must warn: while this 'operator' is easy to find with a simple search query on Google, such code might be not immediately clear to the reader. I strongly suggest using a "normal" for loop, like the one Elliot Frisch mentioned.

Comment: Welcome. I suggest that you take the [tour] of the Help Center, and in particular read the section on [ask]. It's expected that you should do your own research before you post a new question.

Comment: @StephenC Agreed, and amended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not an arrow, but a decrement operator followed by a greater than sign.

What the compiler sees is a less clear version of `(i--) > 0`

Comment: Ahh. Gotcha. It was confusing at first because I've seen more than one person do it in their code. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: *"I've seen more than one person do it in their code."* - Tell them to stop it!

Comment: @MP1 If you found this helpful, don't forget to upvote and accept this answer. (And I agree with Stephen, as you have shown that is unclear.)

Answer (score 1):

It's the post-decrement operator along with the greater than symbol combined which is confusing and unreadable.

it's the same as writing:

```
for(int i = 100; (i--) > 0;) { ... }
```

i.e. `i --> 0` is essentially `(i--) > 0`.

Comment: Actually, because it's post decrement, it's more like: is `(i > 0)` followed by `i = i - 1;`